# What does %VARIABLE% means?

Tags: linux, windows

At many times I see %VARIABLE% (%PYTHON% for exemple) in questions and answers here in Stack Overflow.

I know that this is kinda vague question but I would like to know the meaning of %VARIABLE% more clearly.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer probably depends on the author and context ;-)

[MS Windows console environment variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) are delimited by `%`, so if you saw this in a windows batch script that's most likely a reference to an environment variable of the given name.

In the absence of any context I'd guess your particular example `%PYTHON%` probably means "the filesystem pathname to the Python interpreter", but perhaps the post in question is setting it to something else in context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
The context was related to environment variables

Comment: @PedroBraga the best way to thank a StackOverflow answer is to mark it Accepted (checkmark button) and up-vote it (once you have sufficient reputation)